# Custom Generic Collection Trim class in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a scenario where I want to apply same logic to different types.

```
interface TrimAlgo<T> { 
public List<T> trim(List<T> input);
}

class SizeBasedTrim<T> implements TrimAlgo<T> { 
    private final int size;
    public SizeBasedTrim(int size) { 
        this.size = size; 
    }

    @Override 
    public List<T> trim(List<T> input) { 
         // check for error conditions, size < input.size etc. 
         return input.subList(0, size);
    }
} 

// Will have some other type of TrimAlgo

class Test { 
    private TrimAlgo<?> trimAlgo; 
    public Test(TrimAlgo<?> trimAlgo) { 
       this.trimAlgo = trimAlgo; 
    }

    public void callForString() { 
       List<String> testString = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       testString.add("1");
       trimAlgo.trim(testString); // Error The method get(List<capture#3-of ?>) in the type TrimAlgo<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)
    }

    public void callForInt() { 
       // create int list and call trim on it
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: `where I want to apply same logic to different types` what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to make the `trim()` method generic rather than the `TrimAlgo` class:

```
interface TrimAlgo { 
    <T> List<T> trim(List<T> input);
}
```

After all, it's not like your trimming algorithm itself depends on the type - you can use the same instance to trim both a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Jon. Just one more question, how do I inject SizeBasedTrim to Test?

Comment: @test123: You just pass it in. The parameter becomes simply `TrimAlgo trimAlgo` - lose the generics.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, your earlier comment does mention that. Thanks again!